# Need to develop popup Calendar for a month

Tags: android

I am unable to develop a popUp Calendar for a month where the user can select multiple dates.
Does Android provide any API for such ?
If not , can anyone provide any hints/sample code to develop the same.

Comment: "Does Android provide any API for such ?" -- no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using Android Honeycomb (API 11).  The previous APIs only support the DatePicker class.